# Android Eclipse can't see library's class

Tags: eclipse, admob, mobclix

I have around 5 projects in my Eclipse, all of them were working and compiling just fine but since last eclipse and sdk update I've got a strange bug with mobclix and admob libraries:

**app is compiling fine without any errors but when I open any activity with ads it crashes!**

Error:

`E/AndroidRuntime(22504): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixMMABannerXLAdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.rvanavr.app.apk]`

I've spent a day trying to fix this bug:
- removed/added library
- cleaned project
- reinstalled sdk
- reinsalled everyhing

Did somebody face this bug? Really need you help guys!

Comment: OK I found the solution!

All you need is to create "libs" folder and place all libraries into it, only after this you can add them on projects setting and everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had the same issue yesterday, and found that the problem maybe related to how ANT builds the projects underneath eclipse.  I too started seeing this problem right after I upgraded Eclipse ADT plugin, and also get the latest updates for Android SDKs (API versions 10 and 15).  So, generally based on other stackoverflow questions, I upgraded eclipse as described below, and the problem went away. The way I understand is that Eclipse's build system wasn't including mobclix.jar in the final build, and did not report any errors or warnings to alert this fact.  Here's how I upgrade eclipse:

Eclipse Help Menu -> Install New Software, pops up this window:
[image: Install new eclipse software]

Select "The Eclipse Project Updates" - I'm using version 3.7 (Indigo).  Then click on "Select All", and hit "Finish".  All Eclipse components that aren't up-to-date, will get upgraded to the latest.  And then it'll ask you to restart Eclipse. When I did that, and rebuilt my project, I didn't have any problems with mobclix.jar and undefined classes.

Btw, after the upgrade, here's my Eclipse version (in case you want to compare your current version to mine):

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857